# Error al recibir datos POST

Tags: php, javascript, html

Al cargar por primera vez la pagina almaceno el dni en una variable `$dni`, variable que luego necesito reenviar al ejecutar el submit del form, para esto la guardo como `value` de un input que luego envío por método POST.

El problema es que al recargar la pagina toma como que `$_POST['dni']` está vacío y nunca ejecuta el código correspondiente.

EDIT: el código que adjunto parece funcionar correctamente pero al ejecutarlo en una form con mas entradas simplemente deja de servir. ¿Hay algún limite para la cantidad de datos que puedo enviar?

codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HELP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Apellido:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Apellido"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="dni" value="<?php echo $dni; ?>" readonly hidden></td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="myfunc()">guardar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

codigo php:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['dni'])) {
    $dni=$_POST['dni'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $Apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
}else{
    $dni=$_GET['dni'];
}
?>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(){
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL que utilizas? ¿Estás utilizando el parámetro `?dni=11111111`?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez si, el get tipico

Comment: Y asumo que tu código HTML y tu código PHP está en el mismo archivo.. cierto?

Comment: Ah, ya vi la edición que hiciste, justamente preguntaba porque probé tu código tal como está y parece funcionar bien. En ese caso, ¿qué campos estás agregando de más?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez en total son unos 12 inputs de diferentes tipos pero la estructura es la misma, en el codigo original utilizo un script (que acabo de subir) para hacer el submit al form pero no sé si eso afecte en algo

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es comentar todos los `input`, y comenzar a descomentarlos uno por uno, hasta tener los 12, y tal vez averiguar cuál te da conflicto... Ya que tu código como tal como está no da conflicto y funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día Nicolas, no entendí bien el sentido de tu código, pero siguiendo tu problema acá te brindo una solución que quizás sea de ayuda, lo hice simple siguiendo el desarrollo de tu código. No hay limites para enviar datos con $_POST.

con `strlen(trim($_POST['dni']))==8` compruebo que el dni tenga 8 caracteres, ya que en Argentina tiene 8 caracteres, tú puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en comentarla.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['dni']) && strlen(trim($_POST['dni']))==8) {
    $dni=$_POST['dni'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $Apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
}else{
    if (isset($_GET['dni']) && strlen(trim($_GET['dni']))==8)
    {
        $dni=$_GET['dni'];
    }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HELP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(){
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Apellido:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Apellido"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="dni" value="<?php echo $res=(isset($dni)) ? $dni : '' ?>" readonly></td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="myfunc()">guardar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```